# GPU Monitoring Software for Azure NV6 Servers

Tags: gpu, gpu-monitor

Can anyone recommend any software which exists for monitoring the GPU performance.

Specifically we have "NVIDIA Tesla M60" running on Azure Nv6 servers running Server 2016. It'd be helpful if there is anything at all that could send performance data to Azure Analytics or any other third party solution.

So far I have only been able to see things that give you a live performance chart, but we need something to log the history really.